# MarqueeLabel Swift not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I included the files from [the project](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel-Swift) in mine. I also included the `QuartzCore` Framework in the project.

Here is my main ViewController :

```
class IndexViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: MarqueeLabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Continuous Type
        titleLabel.tag = 101
        titleLabel.type = .Continuous
        titleLabel.scrollDuration = 15.0
        titleLabel.animationCurve = .EaseInOut
        titleLabel.fadeLength = 10.0
        titleLabel.leadingBuffer = 30.0
        titleLabel.trailingBuffer = 20.0

        // ...
    }
}
```

When I try to simulate the project, I get the following error :

`titleLabel.type = .Continuous Thead 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10002)`

Where I'm wrong ?

Comment: i think is not **.continus** it is **. MLContinuous**, check this property oncehttps://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel/blob/master/MarqueeLabel.h

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Not sure it is that with swift. After tried, got an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in Interface Builder that your label's custom class is set to `MarqueeLabel`.

[image]

Comment: Yes ! That's it ! Thank you very much !!